# Android startActivityForResult issue

Tags: android

I am new to Android an I am doing a tutorial on startActivityForResult. I have search through stackoverflow for a answer but I guess I am doing somthing silly. I have two activities A&B and A starts B  and after the user enters some text the activity b is closed and the result is displayed in Activity A. The code is as follows:

```
Activity A:

package course.labs.intentslab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityLoaderActivity extends Activity {

    static private final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    static private final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
    static private final String TAG = "Lab-Intents";

    // For use with app chooser
    static private final String CHOOSER_TEXT = "Load " + URL + " with:";

    // TextView that displays user-entered text from ExplicitlyLoadedActivity runs
    private TextView mUserTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loader_activity);

        // Get reference to the textView
        mUserTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // Declare and setup Explicit Activation button
        Button explicitActivationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.explicit_activation_button);
        explicitActivationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            // Call startExplicitActivation() when pressed
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startExplicitActivation();




            }
        });

        // Declare and setup Implicit Activation button
        Button implicitActivationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.implicit_activation_button);
        implicitActivationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            // Call startImplicitActivation() when pressed
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startImplicitActivation();

            }
        });

    }


    // Start the ExplicitlyLoadedActivity

    private void startExplicitActivation() {

        Log.i(TAG,"Entered startExplicitActivation()");

        // TODO - Create a new intent to launch the ExplicitlyLoadedActivity class
        Intent eX = new Intent(ActivityLoaderActivity.this,ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);

        // TODO - Start an Activity using that intent and the request code defined above

        startActivityForResult(eX,GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE );





    }

    // Start a Browser Activity to view a web page or its URL

    private void startImplicitActivation() {

        Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");

        // TODO - Create a base intent for viewing a URL 


        // (HINT:  second parameter uses parse() from the Uri class)


        // TODO - Create a chooser intent, for choosing which Activity
        // will carry out the baseIntent. Store the Intent in the 
        // chooserIntent variable below. HINT: using the Intent class' 
        // createChooser())

        Intent chooserIntent = null;

        Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());
        // TODO - Start the chooser Activity, using the chooser intent
        startActivity(chooserIntent);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");

        // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
        // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode==GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE){

            // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.


                Intent i= getIntent();



                if(i!=null)
                {

                     String name = i.getStringExtra("name");
                    mUserTextView.setText("me"+name);
                }

                }

        }




    }




Activity B:

package course.labs.intentslab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ExplicitlyLoadedActivity extends Activity {

    static private final String TAG = "Lab-Intents";

    private EditText mEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.explicitly_loaded_activity);

        // Get a reference to the EditText field
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        // Declare and setup "Enter" button
        Button enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter_button);
        enterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            // Call enterClicked() when pressed

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                enterClicked();

            }
        });

    }

    // Sets result to send back to calling Activity and finishes

    private void enterClicked() {

        Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");

        // TODO - Save user provided input from the EditText field

        String userText = mEditText.getText().toString();



        // TODO - Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra

        Intent i = new Intent();

        i.putExtra("name", userText);

        // TODO - Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK

        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);


        // TODO - Finish the Activity

        finish();



    }
}
```

Can someone please spot my error,
Cheers,
Den

Comment: and what seems to be the issue... can you please post if you have a logcat error or something!!

Comment: 03-20 12:00:55.646: I/Lab-Intents(786): Entered enterClicked()
03-20 12:00:55.785: I/Lab-Intents(786): Entered onActivityResult()

Comment: This is the log cat after I press the press enter buton in activity b. But the entered text in Activitty b shows as null in the textview in Activity A...

Comment: You are not setting the activity to be launched on the intent try this

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(actuallActivity.this, ActivityToBeLaunch.class);
intent.putExtra("name", userText);
actuallActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: But if I started the activity wouldn't it no call the resultActivity in Activity A? as I am killing activity b, that will bring activity a back into focus without having to call it?

Comment: I found the problem... I was creating an intent in resultActivity but not assigning the returned intent to the new intent." The line that fixed it is Intent i = data;" Thaanks again, sometime you just need to talk it out with someone...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... I was creating an intent in resultActivity but not assigning the returned intent to the new intent." The line that fixed it is Intent i = data;" Thanks again, sometime you just need to talk it out with someone..